# How do I programmatically create a grid of pixels given only the pixels neighbors

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pixel

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm for building a grid, based on number of pixels and surrounding pixels. For instance let's say I have 200 random pixels. I have pixel a, and I can get references to each pixel surrounding it.  This holds true for all the pixels. In essence each pixel is s puzzle piece, and each piece has a reference to all its neighbors. How do Programmatically creat the grid of pixels ( the finished puzzle ) given that information

Comment: Are the references in any way ordered? A jigsaw piece doesn't just tell you which four it connects to, but in which order. Which would make it relatively easy to construct the outer boundary and then work inwards.

Comment: Actually no, there are no finite boundaries, just an array of objects ( pixels ) that contain an ID, and 4 references to other pixels, one in each direction

Comment: Can you explain what "each pixel is s puzzle piece"  mean ?

Comment: Also, isn't the trivial solution is starting at arbitrary pixel, go to arbitrary neighbor pixel, then continue ? Does the neighbor pixel have reference to its neighbor as well ?

Comment: I'll dry and draw a diagram to better illustrate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your

- **Input** is a list of pixels and each pixel has the attributes `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` (references to the surrounding pixels) and your
- **Output** will be an 2D Array `grid` of pixels,

you can do as follows:

```py
def pixel_graph_to_grid(pixels):
    if len(pixels) == 0:
        return [[]]

    # (1) Finding the top left pixel.
    p = pixels[0]
    while p.top:
        p = p.top
    while p.left:
        p = p.left

    # (2) Go row-wise through the image.
    grid = []
    first_of_row = p
    while True:
        p = first_of_row
        row = [p]
        while p.right:
            p = p.right
            row.append(p)

        grid.append(row)

        if first_of_row.bottom:
            first_of_row = first_of_row.bottom
        else:
            break
```

You can also do some counting similar to `(1)` to know how much memory you have to allocate for the grid.

This algorithm has linear runtime and requires constant extra space, so it should be optimal.